ModernCV - I cannot change the color of references
I have created a ModernCV document. When I cite a paper with \cite{} I want the citation itself to be of a certain color (e.g. HTML 119DA4). Here is my MWE
MWE
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{grey}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{Cover Letter}
% Begin document
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section}
Bla Bla \citep{unfccc1992}
\renewcommand{\refname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}

Inside the file bibliography.bib I have this:
@misc{unfccc1992,
    title = {United Nations Framework Convention on Climate Change},
    author = {{United Nations}},
    year = {1992},
    url = {https://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/conveng.pdf},
    note = {Accessed: 2024-06-06}
}

Attempts
I tried several things, none of them worked.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,citecolor=blue]{moderncv} 
\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 1,linkcolor=blue}}


There is a section in Using colors in Latex with the title " xcolor - only color models " which gives an example of defining a method to use a chosen html color.

@Leucippus hardly relevant. The problem is not the specific color, but the fact that no color shows up

It would seem that if something is to be " hardly relevant " then a clear statement of the problem and desired expected result would be needed in the problem statement rather than a comment later. In addition, given a MWE to view, it would seem that declaring a specific color for a specific line would have been used.

Also, a 12 second Google search yields a result of color in bibliography and many related examples.

\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=black,citecolor=red}} should work.
